# What's the relationship between the NIC's clock and PCIe 2.0 bus?

Tags: network-interface, pci

When I run the list hardware `lshw -class network`, it shows:

```
product: 82599 10 Gigabit Dual Port Network Connection
size: 10Gbit/s
capacity: 10Gbit/s
width: 32 bits
clock: 33MHz
```

Let's suppose we're using an `PCI ex 2.0 .x8` then one can think of the capacity as being: `32 (width) * 33 * 10^6 (clock) * 8 (.x8)` but then it would give me only 8Gbps `(32 * 33 * 10^6  * 8)/1000^3`, what am I missing here?

It uses the PCIeX 2.0 and as far as I know [it can theoretically delivery 500MBps per lane](https://serverfault.com/questions/11633/whats-the-bandwidth-and-form-factor-for-pcie-x1-x4-x8-and-x16).

How can PCIeX 2.0 bus delivery more than the NIC's clock shown by `lshw`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 33 MHz clock is just a reference clock which is used as input to on-chip phase locked loop clock multipliers. A PLL can produce frequencies that are large multiplies of the input frequency. For example, all modern fast CPUs are clocked with an external frequency that is much lower (typically ~100 MHz) than the internal frequency (several GHz).